# How many ec2 compute units would equate a quadcore

Tags: amazon-ec2

How many ec2 compute units of amazon would equate an Intel® Core™ i7-920 Quad-Core.

Comment: You may wish to read this: http://blog.cloudharmony.com/2010/05/what-is-ecu-cpu-benchmarking-in-cloud.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asked another way, which Amazon EC2 instance comes closest to the i7-920. The i7-920 scores 5567 PassMark CPU mark, the Amazon High-CPU Extra Large Instance scores 7962, the Amazon standard Extra Large Instance scores 3627.

http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php

http://huanliu.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/amazons-physical-hardware-and-ec2-compute-unit/